# ASP.NET Core WebApi Return All Values by Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger

My WebApi has a table for applications with the following class:

```cs
namespace Models.Public
{
    [Index(nameof(UUID), nameof(UID), IsUnique = true)]
    public class Application
    {
        public Application()
        {
            this.UUID = new Guid();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Guid UUID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UID { get; set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The field `UUID` and `ID` are unique, so I was able to generate the required `HttpGet` command to obtain the results matching for that.

However, I am trying to obtain an IEnumerable object of all the items that match the `Publisher` field. That is, return all object that have *"Google"* as their Publisher.

My attempts have not been successful and I am hoping for some advise to fix my code:

```cs
// GET: api/Application/<publisher>
[HttpGet("{publisher}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Application>>> GetApplication(string publisher)
{
    var application = await _context.Application.ToListAsync(publisher);

    if (application == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return await _context.Application.ToListAsync();
}
```

`Publisher` is not a unique value, so I'd like to be able to return all items as a JSON object that have whatever Publisher I type in the list. If no matches, error handle with `NotFound();`.

Comment: the relevant code seems to be here: `_context.Application.ToListAsync`, please include that function signature & code

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I have included that in my code as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to filter using `.Where`, `.Contains`

```
// GET: api/Application/<publisher>
[HttpGet("{publisher}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ApplicationData>>> GetApplication(string publisher)
{
    var applications = _context.Application.Where(a=>a.Publisher.Contains(publisher)));

   /* You could also use == for exact match
      var applications = _context.Application.Where(a=>a.Publisher == publisher));
   */

    if (applications.Count() == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return await applications.ToListAsync();
}
```